# Connection Error! java.net.socketTimedoutException:failed to connect to /192.168.1.6 (port : 80) from /192.168.1.7 (port : 53030) after 10000 ms

Tags: java, android

I want to connect with my phone to my app database but I keep seeing this error:

```
Connection Error!  java.net.socketTimedoutException:failed to connect to /192.168.1.6 (port : 80) from /192.168.1.7 (port : 53030) after 10000 ms
```

this is my API class

```java
public class API {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.6/uni/";
    public static Retrofit myRetrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getAPI() {
        if (myRetrofit == null) {
            myRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return myRetrofit;
    }
}
```

I check firewall and turn off window defender and antiVirus
I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246726/java-net-connectexception-failed-to-connect-to-192-168-1-107-port-80-after-1)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618744/how-to-resolve-failed-to-connect-to-192-168-15-186-port-80-connect-failed-e) but none of them solve my issue.
I check the ports in httpd.conf and my app,  also I run my app in emulator and it works fine,  my phone is on the same network as my laptop, so can anyone help me???

Comment: can you share the complete code?

Comment: Can you ping your phone from your pc terminal/command line? My router has an issues and when it happens I reboot the access point and everything starts to work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1905965/amin yes I can ping my phone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7949704/alejandro-gonzalez which part?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Wifi: Check properties, it should be set to Private to connect.