# URL Connection Android 8.0.0

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have a problem, the following code works on Andoid Version 28 but not on 26. Can somebody tell me the difference?

```
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        String reply = result.toString("UTF-8");
```

I get always a ConnectionException: Failed to connect to....

On Android 29 it works perfect.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you paste the complete error message?

Comment: Of course: failed to connect to /192.168.94.1 (port 80) from /192.168.1.107 (port 56684) after 2000ms

Comment: 1. Check if your app has internet permission.
2. try to set android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest tag inside <Application>

Comment: @JaswantSingh I have done both. By the way it is an accesspoint I try to connect to, not an internet URL address. But anyway I have the permission internet ans usesClearTextTraffic = true

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618744/how-to-resolve-failed-to-connect-to-192-168-15-186-port-80-connect-failed-e

Comment: @JaswantSingh Thank you for the link. But unfortunately that also does not solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I have solved the problem myself. The problem was at another code snippet. The connection to the accesspoint wasn't correct in Oreo, so the software couldn't do the urlconnection.